# Select single row without command column in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have used Kendo grid, I need to select a row without command columns.

Here is my code..

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({ 
        dataSource: grid, 
        height: 450,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: "row",
        columns: [
            { field: "user" },
            { field: "subject" },
            { field: "status" },
           { command: ["Update"],  title: "Subscribe" },
            { command: ["destroy "], title: "Delete"}
           ]
    });
```

In UI I want to select user, subject, status only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible out-of-the box, however when you use the select() method you will receive only the data cells. 
If you need it really badly you might use the **change** event of the Grid and search for selected command cells to remove their **k-state-selected** class.

Comment: When you're in row selection mode, only the row has the k-state-selected class, not the individual cells.